# does .net core IOC container is a new implantation?

Tags: .net

does the service collection in the .net core is a new implementation for IOC out of the box of it uses unity internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new implementation.

If you're curious the source for the Dependency Injection code is on GitHub at https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/tree/master/src/DependencyInjection